# php facebook api getAccessToken and setExtendedAccessToken

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the facebook sdk to get a users accessToken and set a long term session (by keeping the key in a database) so they don't have to allow access to the app each time.

I'm trying to get the access token but I'm getting

```
[2014-07-21 18:56:18] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::getAccessToken()' in /var/www/app/controllers/FacebookController.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

My code

```
session_start();
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

class FacebookController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx','xxx');

        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://test.dev/index.php/facebook');

        try {
          $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
          echo 'test 1';
        } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
          // When Facebook returns an error
          echo 'test 2';
          echo '<pre>' , print_r($ex) , ' </pre>';
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'test 3';
          echo '<pre>' , print_r($ex) , ' </pre>';
        }
        if ($session) {
          // Logged in
          echo 'logged in';

          print_r($helper->getAccessToken());


        }else {
          echo 'not logged in ';
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
          echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'user_photos">Login</a>';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the helper to get the access token, you need to be calling that from $session

$session->getAccessToken()

Also if you just want the token itself and not the accessToken object

$session->getToken();